# HERE Maps - dynamically load markers and zooming issue

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I'm trying to use free version of HERE Maps and I want to display markers on the map dynamically. Even though I'm binding the data dynamically it always loads the map that was loaded for the first time. Also, if I zoom in the map it won't go back to the default version even if I set the zoom and centering values. Please provide some inputs if any of you have come across the similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify the following: "it always loads the map that was loaded for the first time". Do you mean the markers never get rendered?
Can you add the code relevant for the map initialization and the creation of the markers?

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos - It loads the map and markers on it with the set of data available for the first time. But if the data changes in the database, map/markers don't refresh even if I try to launch the map for the next time. All I've to do is close the application completely and log back in again to see the latest data. The Map is not dynamic and looks to be static.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos
//Initialize Map Code
this.map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    defaultLayers.normal.map,{
    zoom: 10,
    pixelRatio: pixelRatio
  });
  
  this.map.setZoom(10);
//Marker Code
addMarkerToGroup: function(map, group, coordinate, html) {
    var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
    marker.setData(html);
    map.addObject(marker);
    group.addObject(marker);
 },

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use following code snippet in order to initialise the respective zoom level in the map

```js
function moveMapToBerlin(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
  map.setZoom(14);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:50, lng:5},
  zoom: 4,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
window.onload = function () {
  moveMapToBerlin(map);
}
```